# How can I add SSL certificates to nginx inside a Docker container?

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate, docker

I'm trying to configure SSL on my server but I seem to be going wrong somewhere.

I've purchased SSL certificates on 1&1 and they gave me:

- An intermediate SSL certificate
- My private key
- Another SSL certificate (I'm guessing the normal one?)

A guide online mentioned putting these into a bundle - is this correct?

My nginx and Dockerfile's are below. I used the `-v` command when running docker to map my Linux files to the container, but I'm thinking it would be better to copy the files over in my Dockerfile?

Here's my nginx file:

```
server {
    listen       80;

    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name server_name.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/private/ssl-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/ssl.key;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
}
```

Dockerfile:

```
# build environment
FROM node:9.6.1 as builder
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@1.1.1 -g --silent
COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN npm run build

# production environment
FROM nginx:1.13.9-alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/client/build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding config files into your Dockerfile is not in the Docker best practices.

Your image should be generic, reusable. You may be happy to reuse it as-is later with other certificates files.

So bind mount for configuration is a much better option than putting your config files into the docker image.

About your certs, just concatenate intermediate cert (which should be the certification authority from 1&1), and the other ssl cert (which should be your server cert), into the file ssl-bundle.crt. And private key in ssl.key file.

I also suggest that you explain what is not working, with some logs, or error messages, and also commands you used to spawn & test pour docker container.

Comment: Ah OK, I followed a tutorial which showed doing this, I’ll change it.

Comment: I didn’t get an error message - I just couldn’t access the site using https (or http) with this Nginx configuration

Comment: Does it matter which cert is first in the bundle? (Sort the the million questions!)

Comment: "I just couldn’t access the site" => d.e.t.a.i.l.s please.    is the docker container actually running ? is it listening on ports 80 & 443 ? are you querying the correct ip ? what is the command you used to launch your container ? what about the nginx logs inside ?